# Numba support for big integers?

Tags: python, biginteger, factorial, numba

I have a factorial lookup table that contains the first 30 integer factorials. This table is used in a function that is compiled with `numba.njit`. The issue is, above 20!, the number is larger than a 64-bit signed integer ([9,223,372,036,854,775,807](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_data_type)), which causes [numba to raise a TypingError](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/reference/types.html). If the table is reduced to only include the first 20 integer factorials the function runs fine.

Is there a way to get around this in numba? Perhaps by declaring larger integer types in the jit compiled function where the lookup table is used?

Comment: Are you by any chance trying to compute the probability density of the Beta distribution using Numba?

Comment: @jwalton3141 yes, using [Spouge's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spouge%27s_approximation). I think once I get the [gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function) optimized and accurate, it'll be a nice kernel I can use in many distributions (beta, t gamma).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There may be some way to handle large integers in Numba, but its not a method that I'm aware of.

But, since we know that you're trying to hand-code the evaluation of the [Beta distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution) in Numba, I have some other suggestions.

First though, we must be careful with our language so we don't confuse the [Beta *distribution*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution) and the [Beta *function*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function).

What I'd actually recommend is moving all your computations on to the log scale. That is, instead of computing the pdf of the Beta distribution you'd compute **the log of the pdf** of the Beta distribution.

This trick is commonly used in statistical computing as the log of the pdf is more numerically stable than the pdf. The [Stan project](https://mc-stan.org/), for example, works exclusively to allow the computation of the log posterior density.

From your post history I also know that you're interested in MCMC; it is also common practice to use log pdfs to perform MCMC. In the case of MCMC, instead of having the posterior proportional to the prior times the likelihood, on the log scale you would have the *log*-posterior proportional to the *log*-prior *plus* the *log*-likelihood.

I'd recommend you use log distributions as this allows you to avoid having to ever compute $\Gamma(n)$ for large n, which is prone to integer overflow. Instead, you compute $\log(\Gamma(n))$. But don't you need to compute $\Gamma(n)$ to compute $\log(\Gamma(n))$? Actually, no. You can take a look at the `scipy.special` function [`gammaln`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.0/reference/generated/scipy.special.gammaln.html) which avoids having to compute $\Gamma(n)$ at all. One way forward then would be to look at the source code in `scipy.special.gammaln` and make your own numba implementation from this.

In your comment you also mention using [Spouge's Approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spouge%27s_approximation) to approximate the Gamma function. I've not used Spouge's approximation before, but I have had success with [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation). If you want to use one of these approximations, working on the log scale you would now take the log of the approximation. You'll want to use the [rules of logs](http://www.sosmath.com/algebra/logs/log4/log44/log44.html) to rewrite these approximations.

With all the above considered, what I'd recommend is moving computations from the pdf to the log of the pdf. To compute the log pdf of the Beta *distribution* I'd make use of [this approximation of the Beta *function*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function#Approximation). Using the rules of logs to rewrite this approximation and the Beta pdf. You could then implement this is Numba without having to worry about integer overflow.

#### Edit

Apologies, I'm not sure how to format maths on stack overflow.

Comment: welcome to the 1,000 club (haha, jk). I really appreciate the answer, and while it doesn't address the question directly, taking logs will surely make things a lot easier for my ultimate goal.

Comment: Thanks, I was in two minds as to the appropriateness of my answer (as I know I didn't help handle large numbers in Numba!), but I figured this was another way to solve the underlying problem. I feel using log pdfs is a better long term solution.

Comment: Also, thanks for the club welcome ;) I did wonder whether you'd noticed the significance of your upvote...

Comment: yeah, its certainly more numerically stable. It just involves more numerical approximations and transformations and I want to minimize those to keep the calculation fast and accurate. but logs definitely seem to be the way if implemented correctly

Comment: np, I see you've been answering questions like mad over the last few days. I reckon you'll overtake me within a week or two. you deserve the points!