# Using numba @jit to speed up my multiprocessing loops that use queue

Tags: python, multiprocessing, numba

I am learning the ways of Numba and have not figured out how to use or whether I need to use multiprocessing.queue to combine all my loop data from separate processes.
Do I even want to use the multiprocessing module to break up big loops into multiple smaller ones to run in separate processes or does Numba do this automatically?

The code below is run in the multiprocessing module where it opens up in multiple processes that are divided up into your system core count. So there are many instances of the code running and compute looping through different segments of the overall calculation and then the result 0 or 1 is sent back to the parent function.
My guess is Numba does this differently on its own and I don't want to use queue or the multiprocessing module?

```
@jit(nopython=True)
def prime_multiprocess(n, c, q):
    a, b, c = n[0], n[1], c
    for i in range(a, b):
        if c % i == 0:
            return q.put(0)
    return q.put(1)

This error may have been caused by the following argument(s):
- argument 2: cannot determine Numba type of <class 'multiprocessing.queues.Queue'>
```

I appreciate any explanation or link that explains using numba with parallel loops that speed things up.

Comment: Conceptually, numba takes Python code and converts it into C code that is significantly faster to run.  Numba can only use the most basic elements of Python because it has to use a C equivalent.  In this case, your `q` object is a Python object that numba does NOT know how to use.  You should not include it in your function if you want to use numba.

Comment: Thats what I figured. Thanks James.

Comment: The 'q' parameter in the code is type of <class 'multiprocessing.queues.Queue'> that it doesn't like. I fail to see a work around for passing data back to a parent process from multiple processes without queue.

Comment: Just for reference, there is a comprehensive list of python features that Numba supports here: https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/reference/pysupported.html

Answer (score 0):

I did some testing and it appears that a nested function solved the problem:
I rewrote it to:

```
def prime_multiprocess(n, c, q):
    a, b, c = n[0], n[1], c

    @jit(nopython=True)
    def speed_comp():
        for i in range(a, b):
            if c % i == 0:
                return 0
        return 1
    q.put(speed_comp())
```

It is faster!

edit:
It appears there is a downside to where I am limited to the size of the integers I can use. "sigh" "Why is there always a trade off :( "
I wonder if its possible to workaround this with numpy and if it would slow it down. Answer might be here: [Numba support for big integers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54826611/numba-support-for-big-integers)

The way Numba works is it converts integers into machine-level integers which are limited in scope to your system level such as 64 bit. This is what makes it run faster because there is no overhead on-top of the calculations.  Unfortunately without the overhead slowing things down, you cannot compute bigger integers.